# Is there a prime which is the form of $10^n + 1$ except $2, 11, 101$?

Tags: prime-numbers

Is there a prime which is the form of $10^n + 1$ except $2, 11, 101$?

I confirm there isn't such prime for $n < 64$.

Comment: We know if $n$ has an odd prime factor, the result is composite.  So the only possibilities are for $n$ a power of two.  These grow rapidly enough that heuristic arguments suggest an "expected" number of these primes will be small.

Comment: These are also a special case of _generalized Fermat primes_ and you can find a little more information about them under that name.

Comment: That $10^{2^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10}}}}}}}}}}}+1$ is not prime is almost certain but it's likely to be unprovable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $(10^{n}+1)|10^{n(2k+1)}+1$ for $n$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

According to the **Table** $\boldsymbol{1}$ (page $24$ or $\frac{30}{55}$ of the pdf) from [**this journal**](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1998-67-221/S0025-5718-98-00891-6/S0025-5718-98-00891-6.pdf):

> $10^{2^{n}}+1$ has no (known?) prime factors for $n=13$, $14$, $21$, $23$, $24$, $25$, $\ldots $

That means $10^m+1$ is composite continually for $3\le m \le 8195$.

Comment: @TransfiniteNumbers : n = 2 :) since $10^4+1=73\times 37$

Comment: @Adren Do you mean 10^4+1 = 73 x 137?

Comment: @TransfiniteNumbers  ooops , yes of course