# How many primes are there on the form $100\cdots 0 1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, decimal-expansion

For example 11 and 101 are primes, but apart from them, can we determine how many primes on the form $100\cdots 00 1$ there exist (in decimal number system)?

Comment: I think that it is an open problem. Note that $10^n+1$ is prime implies that $n$ is a power of $2$, though.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108085/is-there-a-prime-which-is-the-form-of-10n-1-except-2-11-101).

Comment: the ones permitted to be prime are $10^{2^n} + 1.$ No guarantees, $10001 = 73 \cdot 137$

Comment: Easy to formulate your problem.....Absolutely another thing is try to solve it.