# Is $10^{2^{21}}+1$ known to be composite?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, fermat-numbers

I looked at the generalized Fermat-prime-numbers. According to factordb, the case $$10^{2^{21}}+1$$ is unknown. Neither a factor is displayed nor $C$ for "composite". Hence my question :

> Is $$10^{2^{21}}+1$$ be known to be composite ? Is a factor known ? If no, what is the search limit ?

Comment: If factordb says it's unknown, why do you think it is known to be composite or  a factor is known?

Comment: [See](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108085/is-there-a-prime-which-is-the-form-of-10n-1-except-2-11-101) "$10^{2^{n}}+1$ has no (known?) prime factors for $n=13$, $14$, $21$, $23$, $24$, $25$, $\ldots $" http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1998-67-221/S0025-5718-98-00891-6/S0025-5718-98-00891-6.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a prime which is the form of $10^n + 1$ except $2, 11, 101$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108085/is-there-a-prime-which-is-the-form-of-10n-1-except-2-11-101)

Comment: @Winther Thank you. What remains is whether the number has been verified for primality.

Comment: @Winther The answer of the linked question does not cover my question. Does your link contain a statement about the primality and/or a search limit for the prime factors ?

Comment: @Ihf Because I do not assume that every verified number or every found factor is in factordb.

Comment: @Ihf Moreover, the status of a number cannot be entered manually in factordb. The program itself must check it.

Comment: A primality check using Maple would be to do this:
    N := 10^(2^21)+1: Power(2,N-1) mod N: evalb(% = 1);
but based smaller examples, this might take a month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PFGW: $$10^{2^{21}}+1$$ is composite: RES64: [651AE2CA2B659AF9] (175710.6149s+0.0590s)

Comment: 0x651AE2CA2B659AF9 does not divide  10^(2^21)+1.